# changing directory access using ICACLS.exe at runtime

Tags: asp.net, iis-7, file-io, permissions

I have the following syntax to change the directory access permission of the LOGO folder in the web application

ICACLS D:\Workspace\SampleProject\LOGO /grant "IIS_IUSRS":(OI)(CI)F.

This works fine if the application is deployed on local IIS, If the web application is hosted on some external server i am not sure what will be the exact path of the LOGO folder,that means cant hard code the path.

so i have written a console application , which gives me the complete path of logo folder on the server and the path is written to sample text file.

my question is their any way to substitute the path "D:\Workspace\SampleProject\LOGO" with the path obtained from text file at runtime ?.

Comment: You can read the path from the text file and pass it to icacls.exe, can't you?

Comment: I guess we can , i am not finding the right syntax to make it work.

Comment: It will help if you post the code fragment which doesn't work (or at least the one which works with hard-coded path)

Comment: This is the correct syntax "ICACLS D:\Workspace\SampleProject\LOGO /grant "IIS_IUSRS":(OI)(CI)F.

Comment: Do you really want to be granting full access?? (i.e. can set permissions for other users too?) And I'm surprised you need this at all - this is just an install step rather than something you need to do at runtime?

Comment: I know the syntax of icacls.exe, what I don't know is what you're doing in your *code* to execute it at runtime.

Comment: Thanks for the reply , runtime is nothing but i have startup task where i am trying to grant permission to IIS_IUSRS using the following syntax "ICACLS D:\Workspace\SampleProject\LOGO /grant "IIS_IUSRS":(OI)(CI)F " ,  i am not sure the path D:\Workspace\SampleProject\LOGO" will be same on the sever where application is hosted, surely the path will be different, so i want to substitute the path which is their on the server for D:\Workspace\SampleProject\LOGO"

Comment: @mahesh: are you using a batch file or what?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as I understand from reading your question and comments, you have a text file with the path of the LOGO folder and you want to run `icacls.exe` from a batch file to set the folder permissions.

Say, your text file is named `path_to_logo.txt` and contains a *single* line with the path. Then the following batch script will do the job:

```
for /F %%l in (path_to_logo.txt) do ICACLS %%l /grant "IIS_IUSRS":(OI)(CI)F
```

`for /f` will loop through all lines in a file (and you have just one), assign the current line to a variable `%l` and execute what follows the `do` keyword.